# SPSS and Python integration: Splitting on a String Variable

Tags: python, string, spss

I have my SPSS dataset with customer comments housed as a string variable.  I'm trying to come up with a piece of syntax that will pull out a word either before or after a specific keyword (One example might be "you were out of organic milk").  If you are wanting to know what type of milk they are talking about, you would want to pull out the word directly before it ("organic").

Through a series of string searches/manipulations, I have it to look for the first space before the word, and to pull out the characters in between. However, I feel like there should be an easier way if I was solely using Python (split on spaces, identify what place the keyword is, and return the word X before or after).  However, I don't know to accomplish this in SPSS using python.  Any ideas for how to approach this problem?

Comment: is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPSS) the spss you're talking about? how are we supposed to help you if we don't have any code to work off of?

Comment: SPSSINC TRANS (custom SPSS Extension command) used with the appropriate RegEx is the way to go here.

Comment: Thanks!  The SPSINC Trans just what I was looking for.